# Using Android navigation architecture component with tab layout

Tags: android, android-tablayout, android-jetpack

I have a tab layout inside a view pager and I switch between fragments based on the position

```
   <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tabs" />
    </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>
```

How do I use navigation component to switch fragments?